# Printing words from a list, to specific coordinates in pygame

Tags: python, list, recursion, pygame

Hey guys I'm looking to print words and numbers from a list. It will contain a list of names, then a seperate list for age.I'm looking to print this into a "excel" looking doc I made with recursion printing rectangles. In a perfect world I could organize a list of each require field and maybe use a loop, telling it to start printing at a certain x position, and print each word a certain x down while going through the loop,, filling the rows easily. Any help would be appreciated. I've tried looking for some printing code for this scenario specifically but couldn't find any. Thanks!

```
import pygame
pygame.font.init()
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 25, True, False)




def main():
    def recursive_draw(x, y, width, height):
        """Recursive rectangle function."""
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, [x, y, width, height], 1)
        if y >= 600:  # Screen bottom reached.
            return
        # Is the rectangle wide enough to draw again?
        elif x < 750 - width:  # Right screen edge not reached.
            x += width
            # Recursively draw again.
            recursive_draw(x, y, width, height)
        else:
            # Increment y and reset x to 0 and start drawing the next row.
            x = 0
            y += height
            recursive_draw(x, y, width, height)

    pygame.init()
    size = [750, 550]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    recursive_draw(0, 0, 150, 50)

    done = False
    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True



        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)


main()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: updated with code sample of what I have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just loop over your data, and increase `y` for each cell, then increase `x` for each row.

Here's how it could look like:

```
import pygame
import pygame.freetype

def recursive_draw(surf, x, y, width, height):
    """Recursive rectangle function."""
    pygame.draw.rect(surf, (0, 0, 0), [x, y, width, height], 1)
    if y >= 600:  # Screen bottom reached.
        return
    # Is the rectangle wide enough to draw again?
    elif x < 750 - width:  # Right screen edge not reached.
        x += width
        # Recursively draw again.
        recursive_draw(surf, x, y, width, height)
    else:
        # Increment y and reset x to 0 and start drawing the next row.
        x = 0
        y += height
        recursive_draw(surf, x, y, width, height)

data = [
    (1, 'RED',    23, 'dog',   41),
    (2, 'BLUE',   12, 'cat',   42),
    (3, 'YELLOW', 12, 'horse', 43),
    (4, 'GREEN',  99, 'bear',  55),
    (5, 'CYAN',   52, 'snake', 14)
]

def main():

    pygame.init()
    font = pygame.freetype.SysFont("Arial", 25, True, False)
    size = [750, 550]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    background = screen.copy()
    recursive_draw(background, 0, 0, 150, 50)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

        # let's have a padding of 15px inside the cell
        x = 15
        y = 15
        for row in data:
            for cell in row:
                font.render_to(screen, (x, y), str(cell), pygame.Color('dodgerblue'))
                x += 150 # should be a constant
            y += 50 # should be a constant
            x = 15 # should be a constant, too :-)

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pygame.quit()
```

[image]

You could use the same approach for drawing the rectangles, so you don't need a recursive function. A nested loop is enough.

---

To read from a file like this (`data.txt`):

```
1, 'RED',    23, 'dog',   41
2, 'BLUE',   12, 'cat',   42
3, 'YELLOW', 12, 'horse', 43
4, 'GREEN',  99, 'bear',  55
5, 'CYAN',   52, 'snake', 14
```

import the `csv` module and use

```
data = []
with open('data.txt', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, quotechar="'", skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)
```

instead of

```
data = [
    (1, 'RED', 23, 'dog',   41),
    ...
]
```

Comment: Would there be a way to print the same format if my data was reading from a .txt file organised like: '1', 'RED', '23', 'dog', '41'......etc.? Ive tried reading a list, stripping it then appending it, but it only prints out the str not the nums, and will show up like R 1st row, E 2nd row, and D 3rd.

Comment: @RocktheFries You should ask another question, since it's an entire different topic, but I've included an example in my answer. You don't have to do the parsing yourself, just use the `csv` module.